Copying bookmarked shapes into new Word document
I have a docx templates which has many shapes and each shape has a bookmark name.
Through a VBA code, I need to copy the shapes, while passing the bookmark name, and paste into destination new Word document.
I had an old template with .doc file format and below VBA code worked.
If SrcDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bmName) Then
  SrcDoc.Shapes(bmName).Select
  WrdApp.Selection.Copy
  DestDoc.Activate
  DestDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Select
  WrdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault

I tried the below lines of code. And the error given for each line of code. Each line tried separately.
SrcDoc.Shapes.Range(Array(bmName)).Select '**-- The item with specified name wasn't found**

SrcDoc.Bookmarks("bmName").Select  '**-- The requested member of the collection does not exist.** 



I've tested your code for docx without issues on M365.

Please try to verify shapes' name, make sure the shape named bmName is exists.


Sub ListShp()
    Dim Shp As Shape
    For Each Shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        Debug.Print Shp.Name
    Next
End Sub



Adding a bookmark doesn't change the shape's name
Test below Word VBA code on a new blank doc.

Sub InserShpBookmark()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                                             Left:=100, _
                                             Top:=100, _
                                             Width:=200, _
                                             Height:=100)
                                             
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:="TestBK"
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TestBK").Start ' 0
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Name ' Rectangle 1
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Shapes("TestBK").Name ' error
End Sub



Hi taller, While adding a new shape to doc I am facing this issue. After adding shape I have added bookmark via insert-->boomarks. but still its not working.

Adding a bookmark doesn't change the shape's name. I've uploaded a snippet for testing.
